# Why is my grid not updating from 'O' to 'S' (ARRAYS)

Tags: java, arrays

Basically i am trying to create a programme where my grid changes from 'O' to 'S' when the user enters co ordinates into the scanner. To me this is the logical way to do it i am new to java and wondering if there is an error to my code the scanners are defiantly working as if i try to print x it comes up with the int the user would of entered. Thankyou in advance.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class TheGame {
 public static void main(String[] args) { {

 System.out.println ("Players Board");


char [][] grid = new char [10][10];
//FILL GRID//
for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
```

{

```
    for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
    {
        grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]='O';
    }

    }
   //END OF FILL GRID//
    //DRAW GRID//
   for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
    {

    System.out.println("");
    for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
    {
    System.out.print(grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]+"  ");
    }
    }
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Choose the Co-ordinates of your first ship");
System.out.println("X = ");
int x = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Y = ");
int y = sc.nextInt(); 

grid[x][y] = 'S';
```

Comment: How do you know your grid is not updating?  You don't print anything after you set a location to `S`.

Comment: oh okay, how would i print the updated grid? and would there be no way to update the grid already shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grid` is indeed changed, but you did not print the grid after the user input, so you did not see the grid changing.

I suggest you extract a method that prints the grid.

```
public static void printGrid(char[][] grid) {
    for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
        {
            System.out.print(grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]+"  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, call this method before and after the user inputs stuff:

```
System.out.println ("Players Board");


char [][] grid = new char [10][10];
//FILL GRID//
for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
{

    for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
    {
        grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]='O';
    }

}
//END OF FILL GRID//
printGrid(grid); // Note the change here
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Choose the Co-ordinates of your first ship");
System.out.println("X = ");
int x = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Y = ");
int y = sc.nextInt(); 

grid[x][y] = 'S';  
printGrid(grid); // Note the change here!
```

Here is a sample run:

```
Players Board

O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  Please Choose the Co-ordinates of your first ship
X = 
3
Y = 
3

O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  S  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
```

Here is the full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println ("Players Board");


    char [][] grid = new char [10][10];
    for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
    {

        for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
        {
            grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]='O';
        }

    }
    printGrid(grid); // Note the change here
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Choose the Co-ordinates of your first ship");
    System.out.println("X = ");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Y = ");
    int y = sc.nextInt();

    grid[x][y] = 'S';
    printGrid(grid); // Note the change here!
}

public static void printGrid(char[][] grid) {
    for(int outerLoopValue = 0; outerLoopValue<10;outerLoopValue++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for(int innerLoopValue = 0; innerLoopValue<10;innerLoopValue++)
        {
            System.out.print(grid[outerLoopValue][innerLoopValue]+"  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are telling me to do however i dont really understand the coding and the methods you used for example why is the printgrid now in public static void? should that be the main class?

Comment: @Chop That should be in the main class. You can declare it private if you want. I don't think it matters much in such a small program (unless this isn't your full code). The `static` is there so as to access it from a static context,  your `main` method.

Comment: This is the error i am getting when main string args is replaced with your code: Error: Main method not found in class TheGame, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: @Chop You should make `main` look like my second code snippet, and put `printGrid` _alongside_ the `main` method.

Comment: i did and this didnt work, if you copy and paste your code straight into java would does it work for you? sorry to be a trouble im very ameteur at this and under stress for my assignment this is for.

Comment: ah i think i need to do this in main, you see the prgram will be developed into a battleships game once i have this down. so i will need 3 different grids for the player cpu and shots fired. When i copy your example im still getting the exact same error as before. I dont know where i am going wrong.

Comment: @Chop According to the error message, you seem to be creating a JavaFX application. The code in your question does not show that. Try creating a command line project using your iDE and put my code in. If you want to know how to do this in JavaFX, then that's a whole other story altogether. I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: i just want it in the console idk what java fx even is haha. The code used was similar to my tutors for creating the grid with 'O's.

Comment: @Chop Right. You need to create a new project then. This time, don't select anything like "JavaFX" and look for "Console application" or "Command Line".